# Prometheus: PromQL Subtraction, same label, different value

Tags: prometheus, grafana, hystrix

I'm using Hystrix, micrometer, prometheus.

The following query works, but I need to modify it and I don't know how:

```
sum by(group, key) (increase(hystrix_execution_total{event="exception_thrown"}[1m])) / sum by(group, key) (increase(hystrix_execution_terminal_total[1m])) * 100 >= 5
```

Basically `exception_thrown` is one event emitted by Hystrix, but Hystrix also emits another metric `bad_request` which signifies a client error (400). To get an accurate measure of upstream server errors, I need to subtract two metrics, which have the same labels, but different values, and then get a rate per minute to alert on

```
hystrix_execution_total{job="auth",key="authenticate",event="exception_thrown"} - hystrix_execution_total{job="auth",key="authenticate",event="bad_request"}
```

any ideas if it is possible to achieve this?
[image: Prometheus Graph of 2 metrics which need to be subtracted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ignoring worked once someone pointed out that there was more than 1 difference between the label values.

Not only was the *event* label value different, but there was a corresponding difference in the *terminal* label value. For *exception_thrown*, *terminal*=true, for *bad_request*, *terminal*=false[!

```
sum by(group, key) (increase(hystrix_execution_total{job="auth",key="authenticate",event="exception_thrown"}[10m]) - ignoring(event, terminal) increase(hystrix_execution_total{job="auth",key="authenticate",event="bad_request"}[10m])) / sum by(group, key) (increase(hystrix_execution_terminal_total[10m])) * 100 >= 5
```